# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (68,700) into shape (68,1)

Tags: arrays, shapes, broadcast, valueerror

I am trying to run some simulations using python's notebooks and can't solve a problem that popped up.

I am using this function:

```
def simulateKM(conn, K, simlength, omega, D, dt):
    N = conn.weights.shape[0]
    KM = models.Kuramoto(omega=np.array(omega)) 
    hiss = noise.Additive(nsig=np.array([(D)]), noise_seed=1)
    sim = simulator.Simulator(
        model=KM,        
        connectivity=conn,
        conduction_speed=np.float(conn.speed),
        coupling=coupling.Kuramoto(a=np.array([K/N])),
        integrator=integrators.HeunStochastic(dt=dt, noise=hiss), 
        monitors=[monitors.TemporalAverage(period=40.0)]
    )
    
    sim.initial_conditions = np.random.rand(1,1,N,1)*2*np.pi 

    sim.configure()    
    
    [(t, tavg_data)] = sim.run(simulation_length=simlength)
    
    theta = np.squeeze(np.array(tavg_data))

    return [(t, theta)]
```

And these variables:

```
N = con_cortex.weights.shape[0] 
time_max  = 200 
K_values = np.arange(1,8,0.01) 
dt = 0.01 
omega = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)  
t_values = np.arange(1,time_max+1,dt)
D = 0.001
```

Running the simulation:

```
theta = simulateKM(con, K_values, time_max, omega, D, dt)
```

And this error occurs:

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (68,700) into shape (68,1)

I think that the error is in K_values, because it's an array with plenty of values, but I can't solve it. Does anyone know how I can do it or can give any advice?

Thank you for your time.